# Meteor 0.9.x Update

Tags: meteor

How do I find out what is holding my app up from updating? I keep getting the 'This project is at the latest release which is compatible with your current package constraints.' message.

Here is the output from the update command:

```
Refreshing package metadata. This may take a moment.
Figuring out the best package versions to use. This may take a moment.
Figuring out the best package versions to use. This may take a moment.
Figuring out the best package versions to use. This may take a moment.
This project is at the latest release which is compatible with your
current package constraints.
```

My packages.js looks like so:

```
# Meteor packages used by this project, one per line.
#
# 'meteor add' and 'meteor remove' will edit this file for you,
# but you can also edit it by hand.

accounts-base
accounts-password
alanning:roles@=1.2.9
arunoda:npm@0.2.6
ch-activity
ch-activityreport
ch-arrestreport
ch-assetreport
ch-citation
ch-fieldinterviewreport
ch-incidentreport
ch-inspectionreport
ch-location
ch-media
ch-narrative
ch-organization
ch-person
ch-property
ch-signature
ch-vehicle
cmather:iron-router@0.8.2
coffeescript
copleykj:mesosphere@0.1.9
d3
dash-patrol
email
less
mizzao:bootboxjs@4.2.1-master.1
mrt:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3@=0.3.3
mrt:leaflet@0.3.8
mrt:mongo-counter@1.1.0
notices
sacha:spin@2.0.4
standard-app-packages
tsega:bootstrap3-datetimepicker@=0.2.0
```

I have migrated all the ch-* and dash-* packages to the new format. Those are local, in app, packages. Those cannot be in public repositories.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try replacing

```
cmather:iron-router@0.8.2
```

with

```
iron:router@0.9.1
```

in your packages file.

Comment: Thanks. This solved my problem: `meteor update` from 0.8 stopped at 0.9.2. After this hint, I've correctly updated to 0.9.4 without problems.

Answer (score 1):

I'm think it may be because not all your packages are compatible with Meteor 0.9.0
If you want to check what packages are currently compatible enter this code:

```
meteor search (Package Name)
```

By default meteor will only return compatible packages, so you can find which packages aren't working by searching each one.  If you can't find the package, then its probably not compatible and you aren't going to be able to run the latest version of Meteor unless you remove it.

Don't worry though!  While Meteor 0.9.0 is quite buggy, they are working hard to update all the packages and patch the bugs.  Just give it a few weeks to sort itself out if that doesn't work :)

Best Of Luck!  Hope This Helped!

Comment: Sure it is. Are you on Meteor 0.9.x?

Answer (score 1):

Meteor search is included in the latest release.  Docs: http://docs.meteor.com/#meteorsearch

Try running this command and you should be able to access meteor search

```
meteor update
```

Also, the update should tell you if there's a package update available, although I had to run update (packagename) on each starred package for it to update

```
meteor update aldeed:collection2
```

Comment: Can someone explain why this worked for me? Why did I have to explicitly execute 'meteor update packagename'?

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had to remove my `~/.npm` directory and run `meteor` again to resolve some npm dependencies I had. Perhaps you have some npm dependencies as well?