# Cannot update 0.8.3 -> 0.9.2.1

Tags: meteor

I am attempting to upgrade 0.8.3 -> 0.9.2.1 using `meteor update` however I am getting:

```
Refreshing package metadata. This may take a moment.
Figuring out the best package versions to use. This may take a moment.
Figuring out the best package versions to use. This may take a moment.
Figuring out the best package versions to use. This may take a moment.
Figuring out the best package versions to use. This may take a moment.
This project is at the latest release which is compatible with your current package constraints.
```

And it stays on 0.8.3. `meteor update --release 0.9.2.x` doesn't do anything either.

The issue is similar to this [Meteor 0.9.x Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25557082/meteor-0-9-x-update) however I am still on 0.8.3 after running `meteor update` and therefore the new Meteor CLI commands aren't available to me.

Any idea how to upgrade my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have some packages in your project, which aren't able to upgrade automatically.

- try to remove all non-native packages (everything you added with `mrt` from atmosphere)
- run the `meteor update` command
- add the packages with the new namespace syntax with `meteor add`
- be happy :-)

This worked fine for me.